# Creating animated graphics to symbolize selections in ArcGIS Explorer?

Tags: visualisation, arcgis-explorer

I want to create and add some animated graphics to the features based on a query in ArcGIS Explorer, like some moving waves at the queried features.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is ArcGIS Explorer a strong requirement?  It might be easier to make moving wave symbols using the [Silverlight/WPF SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#CustomSymbols)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an animated theme (layer) in ArcExplorer - KML/KMZ is best supported to do this

[image]

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/900/en/time_based_animations.htm

You need to create a timeline to have the layer animated.

As for graphic create a layered gif or png and add into ArcExplorer as a point feature.

For ArcGIS (9.2 onwards) there is the animation toolbar
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/animationinarcmap_tutorial_index.htm